# A template of a crc module

Tags: c++

It is my first experience in templates.

This module generates a crc table depending on a polynomial and calculates a 
 result value in its method.

Could you please review it?

```
    #ifndef CRC_H  // An unmultiplay file loading macros,
    #define CRC_H  // define the one.

    /* Include files: */
    #include "platform.h"  // a platform depend settings.

    #define CRC_DEBUG_COUT       ENABLE// The enable to print debug messages to a console.


    namespace CrcSpace {   // The class namespace.


        const u32 crcTableSize  = 256; // A CRC table size.

        /* CRC8 polynomials: */
        enum u8Poly  {etsiPoly  = 0xD5,    // the ETSI polynomial.
                      maximPoly = 0x31};   // the MAXIM polynomial.

        /* CRC16 polynomials: */
        enum u16Poly {ibmPoly   = 0x8005,  // the IBM polynomial.
                      ccitPoly  = 0x1021}; // the CCIT polynomial.

        /* CRC32 polynomials: */
        enum u32Poly {posixPoly = 0x04C11DB7}; // the POSIX polynomial.
    }


    /* The class definition. */
    template <typename T>
    class Crc {
    private:
        T initValue;
        T finalXor;

    protected:
       T crcTable[CrcSpace::crcTableSize] = {}; // An initialization of crc table.

    public:
        Crc(T polynomial,T initValue, T finalXor); // The class constructor declaration.
        ~Crc();                                    // The class destructor declaration.

        status calculate(void *pData, u32 dataArraySize, T &crc);   // the calkulation crc method.
    };


    //**********************************************************************
    // The class constructor definition.
    //**********************************************************************
    // Description:    The method generates a crc table depending on
    //                 A polynomial.
    //
    // polynomial:     A polynomial depending on which will be generated the
    //                 crc table.
    //
    // initValue:      A first init value.
    //
    // finalXor:       F final  XOR value.
    //
    // return:         Non.
    //
    template <typename T>
    Crc<T>::Crc(T polynomial,T initValue, T finalXor) : initValue(initValue),  finalXor(finalXor) {

       T temp = 0;

       for(u32 tabIndexCounter = 0; tabIndexCounter < CrcSpace::crcTableSize; ++tabIndexCounter) {

           temp = static_cast<T>(tabIndexCounter);

           for (u32 bitCounter = 0; bitCounter < PlatformSpace::byteSize; ++bitCounter) {

               if(temp & (1 << (sizeof(T) * PlatformSpace::byteSize - 1))) {

                   temp = (temp << 1) ^ polynomial;
               }
               else {

                   temp <<= 1;
               }
           }

           *(this->crcTable + tabIndexCounter) = temp;
       }
    }


    //**********************************************************************
    // The class destructor definition. */
    //**********************************************************************
    // Description:    non.
    //
    // parameters:     non.
    //
    template <typename T>
    Crc<T>::~Crc() {
        // It is empty yet.
    }

    //**********************************************************************
    // A definition of the template method the calculate.
    //**********************************************************************
    // Description:    The method calculates a crc result depending on
    //                 received data.
    //
    // pData:          Data fot a crc calculate.
    //
    // dataArraySize:  Size of the received data.
    //
    // crc:            The crc result.
    //
    // return:         A status of the method perform
    //                 (ok == 0 aka success and error == -1 aka failure).
    //
    template <typename T>
    status Crc<T>::calculate(void *pData, u32 dataArraySize, T& crc) {

       u8 *pByteBata = reinterpret_cast<u8*> (pData);

       if((pByteBata == nullptr) || (dataArraySize == 0)) {

           return StatusSpace::error;
       }

       crc = this->initValue;

       for(u32 dataCounter = 0; dataCounter < dataArraySize; ++dataCounter) {

           crc = (crc >> 8 ^ this->crcTable[crc ^ *(pByteBata + dataCounter)]);
       }

       crc ^= finalXor;

       return StatusSpace::ok;
    }

    #endif // CRC_H
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Remove the trivial destructor

The destructor is not doing anything, so there's no need to write it at all.

## Make it clear what types `T` are allowed

Currently your code allows the instantiation of the class with any type `T`. However, it probably only makes sense for unsigned integral types. Furthermore, you probably want to restrict it to only the polynomials you have defined in `CrcSpace`, since not all generators result in useful CRCs.

It would be better if you could pass the desired polynomial directly as the template argument to `class Crc`. Here is a possible implementation:

```
namespace CrcSpace {
    template<typename T, T value_>
    struct Polynomial {
         using value_type = T; 
         static constexpr T value = value_;
    };

    using etsi = Polynomial<u8, 0xD5>;
    ...
    using posix = Polynomial<u32, 0x04C11DB7>;
}

template <typename P>
class Crc {
    using T = typename P::value_type;

private:
    T initValue;
    ...

public:
    Crc(T initValue, T finalXor);
    ...
};
```

You'd the instantiate a `Crc` like so:

```
Crc<CrcSpace::etsi> crc(9, 42);
```

## Use array notation where appropriate

This line:

```
*(this->crcTable + tabIndexCounter) = temp;
```

Looks very complex, but it's just writting to an array element. It should be rewritten as:

```
crcTable[tabIndexCounter] = temp;
```

## Don't write `this->` unnecessarily

You use `this->variable` in many places where the `this->` part is unnecessary. Unlike Python, you don't need to write `this->` everywhere in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your reply) Could you say, why it need?    
        struct Polynomial { 
        using value_type = T;  static constexpr T value = value_;};